# Use of DotNet HighCharts dll to make charts in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, highcharts

I just discovered the DotNetHighCharts dll to make charts:
http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/

I added the dll to my project and put a sample code to get a pie in my Page_Load event ( i'm not working with MVC right now, so i just took what was in the controller of the demo )

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
        .InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
        .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010" })
        .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }" })
        .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
        {
            Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
            {
                AllowPointSelect = true,
                Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
                DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                {
                    Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                    ConnectorColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                    Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }"
                }
            }
        })
        .SetSeries(new Series
        {
            Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
            Name = "Browser share",
            Data = new Data(new object[]
                                       {
                                           new object[] { "Firefox", 45.0 },
                                           new object[] { "IE", 26.8 },
                                           new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Point
                                           {
                                               Name = "Chrome",
                                               Y = 12.8,
                                               Sliced = true,
                                               Selected = true
                                           },
                                           new object[] { "Safari", 8.5 },
                                           new object[] { "Opera", 6.2 },
                                           new object[] { "Others", 0.7 }
                                       })
        });

    }
}
```

}

the problem is that northing appears in my page with this
Is there anything to add ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at my entry on an alternative of generating charts (using HighCharts) in .NET in less than 5 lines.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413606/using-highcharts-javascript-in-web-application/12750922#12750922

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the library but all this code appears to be doing is creating an object in the code behind.  You will need to do something to cause this to render in to the page.

Looking at their example code behind code there is a line

```
ltrChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
```

This is the bit you are missing.  You need to call ToHtmlString() on your chart object and assign this string to a literal or placeholder in the page.

To create the literal just add this code somewhere on the page....

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltrChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

...and your chart should appear there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but i just tried this & it's unfortunately not working even though it looked coherent

Comment: Could be something wrong with the construction of the chart object itself.  Have you tried just copying the chart constructor in the demo http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/ (point 3 under how it works).  Check if that works - it will narrow down the problem at least.

Comment: Also to check - are you including the necessary javascript in your page (point 2 under how it works).  Are you sure this script is being correctly referenced?

Comment: Thanks, i had indeed a problem with my referenced JS pages ... i forgot to add JQuery.
Thanks a lot for your help dude

Answer (score -1):

Based on their example you need to send the HTML to the client side with the line

```
Response.Write(result);
```

It works to me, though it prints it at the top of the screen and I wish I could set the position for it.