# Using a C# variable in HighCharts tooltip

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I have a highchart basic bar type with an X axis Percentage, and Y Axis labelled e.g. 'Student'

Imagine each bar represents a test. My tooltip at the moment reads

Student 1- Geography 70%   History 50%   I.T. 40%

My tooltip options are simply

```
        .SetTooltip(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Tooltip
        {
            ValueSuffix = "%",
            Shared = true

        })
```

What I want is a way to be able to incldue the raw score as well as the percentage. I.e. the percentage is calculated outside of the chart creation and passed in to the seriesData as an array of percentages (for each student)

Is there a way in which I can show the raw score alongside this, maybe using the .SetTooltip formatter option?

I've played about with some inline javascript like so:

```
    Formatter = @"function() { return this.x + ' <b>'+this.series.options.name+'</b> ' + this.y + '%'; }"
```

I've set the ID in seriesData to the score of each test, the raw score, and could maybe access it using series.Id but I haven't really gotten anywhere. I'm really struggling with using DotNet.HighCharts and having to code it in C# as I haven't been able to find a lot of documentation.

Hopefully what i'm trying to do is clear enough, and if not let me know.

Thanks

Comment: How about this solution: setting point format:`PointFormat = '{series.name}: {point.y}% ({point.options.otherValue})` and passing information to the point about that values? Something like this (sorry JS only: http://jsfiddle.net/oLa7w0es/ - note the structure of points!).

Comment: Interesting, this looks promising. Do you know how I can pass my object in as a 2D array to the data helper in C#?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not a C# dev :( Maybe some of your code could help me to help you? Like how do you create series?

Comment: How about [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225480/use-of-dotnet-highcharts-dll-to-make-charts-in-code-behind) - question is unrelated, but `new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Point`is interesting part - could you try it with adding `otherValue`?